# how to add a constant to an entire column in google sheets

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have some data that i want to add a time stamp to. Currently I'm doing this by running a loop, and adding the data to colomn 51 with the code below:

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")   
var NewLastRow = ss.getLastRow();
for (var i = 3; i < NewLastRow; i++) {
ss.getRange(i,51).setValue(date);
ss.getRange(i,52).setValue("New_Orders");
   }
```

this works, but seems super slow to run over 5000+ rows. Is there a better way to do this where i don't have to use a for loop and just assign the entire column with the a constant date value?

thanks

Comment: Why haven't you searched for similar questions? Why didn't you read best practices? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution you are looking for:

```
function myFunction() {
  
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1")
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-4", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
var NewLastRow = ss.getLastRow()

ss.getRange(3, 51, NewLastRow , 1).setValue( Array(NewLastRow).fill(date) )
ss.getRange(3, 52, NewLastRow , 1).setValue( Array(NewLastRow).fill("New_Orders") )

}
```

You should avoid using the function setValue() inside of a loop.

Comment: There is a better top voted answer there

Comment: I know, but push gives the flexibility to add also different values. It is a more generic approach in GAS and it is often overlooked.

Comment: In your latest script, where `setValue` is used, You don't need a array. Just a string/date object will do.